# JQuery: didnt get button id on click

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem in the jquery click event.
actually i was append some **tr** in table. my code is given below.

***HTML CODE:***

```
 <table id="tblList">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Country Name</th>
                    <th>CityName</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```

***JQUERY CODE:***

`var rowsCount = $("#tblList tbody").find("tr").length;
var table = "<tr><td>" + countryName + "</td><td>" + cityName + "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><div id='divGridRow'><input type='button' value='add Zip Code' id='btn" + rowsCount + "' class='gridButton'/></div></td></tr>";
$('#tblList').append(table);`

above code is working fine. now i want to show dialog when click on my **addZipCode** button.

i was write below code for get the button id.

```
 $("#tblList tbody").bind('click', function() {
    $(this).find("tr").bind('click', function() {
        $(this).find("input").bind('click', function() {
            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    });
});
```

but still not successful to get button id 100%. In the above code i have face one more issue. 
if i click first time on button, no value display in **console.log**, when click third time,then only one time BUTTON ID is display **btn0** and when i click fourth time then button id is display three time
**btn0
btn0
btn0**
and when i click fifth time then button id is display 6 time atones like this
**btn0
btn0
btn0
btn0
btn0
btn0**

i append multiple rows in table, and every button in row have a unique id like btn0, btn1,btn2.....
simple i want to try to get button id on click.

please help me to find the solution. Thanks in advance.

please check your self in jsfilddle
http://jsfiddle.net/umairnoor84/y25LW/

Comment: how you calculated the rows count

Comment: Do you **really** want to bind new events on each click? I somehow cannot believe that. Please post your HTML code (not as a JS string but properly indented) and on which element you want the click event to give you the ID of which element.

Comment: Why have you nested all the binds. TR bind will happen when you click 1st and input button will happen after you click on a tr. No doubt button is working after 4th click.

Comment: 'var rowsCount = $("#tblList tbody").find("tr").length;'

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do?! why all those binding?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You're rebinding the "click" event every time "#tbList tbody" is clicked...

Comment: i append multiple rows in table, and every button in row have a unique id like btn0, btn1,btn2.....
simple i want to try to get button id on click.

Comment: Why a downvote ??? its pretty obvious that @Umair Noor is new on site, so he has not formatted the question well.I guess we shud hlp him wid dis n also imp to mention dat You should try to embed html in javascript to bare minimum. 4 dis u can use template plugin like jQuery.templ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only bind the click handler on the buttons (elements with the class `gridButton`).
Try this:

```
$('#tblList .gridButton').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

=== UPDATE ===

You should append the row not to the `table`, append it to the `tbody` of this table:
Replace

```
$('#tblList').append(table);
```

with

```
$('#tblList tbody').append(table);
```

=== UPDATE ===

Because the rows will be added dynamically, you have to change the code to:

jQuery 1.7 ([here a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y25LW/5/)):

```
$('body').on('click', '#tblList .gridButton', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

before jQuery 1.7 ([here a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y25LW/1/)):

```
$('#tblList .gridButton').live('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Here [your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y25LW/1/) with my "before 1.7"-version

Comment: You're welcome. It would be fair if you would [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) of your choice for all your questions (no reputation needed).

Comment: this is the answer of my question 

i was use below code 

    $("#tblList tbody").bind('click', function() {
        $(this).find("tr").bind('click', function() {
            $(this).find("input").bind('click', function() {
                console.log($(this).attr("id"));
            });
        });
    });

but my problem was solve by this code.

    $('#tblList .gridButton').live('click', function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    });


thanks for all, who was give the answer. specially thanks for @scessor because this problem is solve with the help of scessor.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you click on tbody, it attaches a handler to click event for tr. Then, if you click on tr, it attaches a handler to click events for input. The more times you click on them, the more times the hander is attached.
So if you just want to print inputs id:

```
$("#tblList input").bind('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

EDIT:

```
$("#tblList input").live('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please make a jsfiddle. It makes things much easier for people to help out.

Your problem is that you bind the click events **inside** a click event, which will cause a cascade of click bindings on every click. Just bind the "click" event on the button.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cpMGQ/

**Edit:** Here's what you would want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/cpMGQ/1/

```
function addRow(country, city, rowCount) {
    var table = "<tr><td>" + country+ "</td><td>"
        + city + "</td></tr>" 
        + "<tr><td colspan='2'><div id='divGridRow'><input type='button' value='add Zip Code' id='btn" 
        + rowCount + "' class='gridButton'/></div></td></tr>";

    $('#tblList').append(table);

    $('#btn' + rowCount).click(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));    
    });
}

addRow("country 1", "city 1", 1);
addRow("country 2", "city 2", 2);
```

Comment: please check your self in jsfilddle
[http://jsfiddle.net/umairnoor84/y25LW/](http://jsfiddle.net/umairnoor84/y25LW/)